# AngularJS - would calling $apply() affect the performance when model becomes large?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and I really like [the way $apply() works](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html). I am making a chat application now. Every time the client receives friends' messages, the model is changed without Angular notice and thus I need to call $apply().

I just do a quick test with 10k messages exist in the model, every time a new message comes, $apply needs 1 sec to finish its dirty checking.

So, my question is: Does angular really suit this type of app?

Comment: If you need 10K messages in the model I'd say that Angular is not a good fit for your app, at least not before `Object.observe()` is available!

Comment: @joakimbl I am quite new to MVC frameworks on front-end, do you think emberjs/backbone will fit a chat app with chatrooms having *a lot of*  messages?

Comment: If you really wanted to display 10k messages in a chat client, you'd rather have a usability problem than a framework problem. Maybe you do not want to display all those 10k messages, but drop out old ones. That amount of messages would rather be a problem for your users than for the framework you are using.

Comment: @Tharabas: Ok, that was not a good example, I am just curious about how MVC framework does View and Model binding and handles the case where models become really large. For e.g: When a single message is added, Angular takes the approach that goes check the whole model for changes and so it gets much slower when the model grows. If we use setter and geter which probably know the added message is the only change, we can just update the view accordingly without going through the model again. I am not sure Emberjs or any MVC framework does that so I am asking :P

Comment: Misko (creator of Angular.js) once said: "If you have <1000 bindings Angular.js works fast enough, if you have >1000 bindings on a single page, you are doing something really wrong". Backbone does not dirty check its collection, it uses events, so an add to the collection can be faster, but it has flaws at another use case. Just dont create 10000 items in the model. Your users will thank you.

Comment: @OlivérKovács: Thanks, I will definitely limit the max number of messages .

Comment: One thing that's easy to get confused about with angular is scope vs model.  Putting 10K items on the scope is less than great for performance.  You probably want to have an angular service manage your data with a local, persistent or some combination of those store- and then feed small chunks of that data to the appropriate scope as needed with a controller arbitrating the exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when monitoring remote terminal. Did you really need to store messages in a model? May be transclusion could work for you by storing messages in DOM with directives?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZJSz4/42/).

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <button ng-click="add(test)">Add message</button>
    <ng-message>Text 1</ng-message>
    <ng-message>Text 2</ng-message>
    <ng-message>Text 3</ng-message>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module("main", [])
.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.test = 'Test Message';
})
.directive("ngMessage", function ($compile) {
    return {
        template: '<div ng-transclude><b>Heading <br></b></div>',
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        link: function (scope, elm) {
            scope.add = function(text){
               elm.after($compile('<ng-message>' + text + '</ng-message>')(scope));
            }
        }
    };
});
```